# Laravel - Carbon Not Factoring in Daylight Savings Time

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon in Laravel to do some work on dates. I quickly realized that my local copy of PHP was set for UTC, so in my code I'm setting the timezone in Carbon:

```
$dt = Carbon::now('America/New_York');
```

Strangely, it's still spitting out a date that is one hour behind New York time:

```
echo $dt;
```

Yields:

> 2017-07-25 16:29:37

But it is currently 5:29pm

It seems as though it's an hour off because it's not factoring in daylight savings time. I can't find anything on StackOverflow or Google related to daylight savings time in Carbon, everything I read just says if you set the timezone correctly, it will account for DST on its own.

Comment: have you checked the `datetime` in your `php.ini` file and check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732548/carbon-now-time-wrong)

Comment: I checked my php.ini, it's set to the same thing: date.timezone = "America/New_York"

Unfortunately I didn't find anything else in the answer you linked to that would explain this either.

Comment: try to echo time using native php function like `echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");` and see if you get the correct time according to your timezone

Comment: Confirmed, this does output the right time. I also echoed my phpinfo() just to ensure that the PHP being executed is the same PHP as the php.ini I checked the timezone setting on. Timezone matched what I set in php.ini

Comment: have you set the timezone in your laravel config?

Comment: Check the settings in `laravel/config/app.php` line ~ 67 -> `'timezone' => __`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove where you are setting the timezone with Carbon.

Inside `config/app.php` there is a line:

```
'timezone' => ''
```

set it to:

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
```

It will set the default timezone for your app. After setting that you will get the DST adjusted New York time.