# Laravel date_format, timezones, DST and validation

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, dst

I'm trying to validate a date in a request to a controller in Laravel.

Basically I want to validate the date `2023-03-26T02:15:00.000Z`. This date and time without the `Z` does not exist in my timezone (`Europe/Zurich`) because of DST. But since there's a `Z` at the end, I expect Laravel to "get" it and check in the right timezone.

I'm not sure it's a PHP bug, maybe more that I'm not doing it right. Any idea how I could achieve my goal?

Laravel request validation rules:

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'date' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z',
        ];
    }
```

[Smallest code to reproduce](https://www.phplayground.com/s/(%27code!%27%3C%3Fphp7GAll%203%20dOsQbjthjsamj77dO_default_timezone_set%7B%22Europe%2FZurich%22V77POKMR29k7yKMY-m-dNNTH%3Ai%3As.vNNZk7JO*SIQdo7P14qnew%20xZone%7B%22UTC%22%7DVJ1XSLaravel%20does7P24VJ2X39%27%7Eversion!%278.2%27)*%20.%20M%5C7k%20GR4Kx%3A%3AcreOFromFBqPO7%5Cn9%3A15%3A00.000ZBg%7ByG%2F%2F%20J7echo%20PK%20%3D%20M%5C%27N%5C%5COateP%24dQ%20should%20R2023-03-26T0S2977GWhat%20V%7D%3BX-%3EfB%7D*gormatje%20kM%3Bq%2C%20xDOTimey%24fg%01yxqkjgXVSRQPONMKJGB974*_):

```php
<?php
// All 3 dates should be the same 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
// Laravel config/app.php:
// 'timezone' => 'Europe/Zurich',

$date = "2023-03-26T02:15:00.000Z";
$format = "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.v\\Z";

echo $date . "\n"; // 2023-03-26T02:15:00.000Z

// What I should do
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d1->format($format) . "\n"; // 2023-03-26T02:15:00.000Z

// What Laravel does
$d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
echo $d2->format($format) . "\n"; // 2023-03-26T03:15:00.000Z
// which results in an invalid date because it's not the same as $date
```

So how can I tell Laravel to validate the date in the `UTC` timezone?

Comment: Seems to have something to do with Daylight Savings in Zurich. Perhaps Carbon can offer a solution. [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Maybe this answer helps as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27733033/9636400

Comment: Yes it has to do with Daylight Savings. How should I use Carbon to validate request parameters in Laravel?

Comment: Carbon is not used to validate those params. Its basically DateTime just more advanced. Has some nifty functions regarding localization. Check out this to get an insight as to how it works:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-utc-daylight-savings-time-error

Comment: You might need to write a custom validation rule to validate the date against UTC instead of it converting it to the app timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following format should accept your date:

```php
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2023-03-26T02:15:00.000Z');
```

You can also use lowercase `p`, see the difference here:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

This is basically an edit for `\DateTimeInterface::ATOM = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'` which does not accept microtime by default.

Your setting of `date_default_timezone_set(...)` or `config/app.php::timezone` should not matter in this case since your date specifically passes `"Z"` which is `UTC+0`. However leaving out the `P` from the required format AND your input will default to your given timezone.